# Wolfram alpha, third root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

As I learned, the third root of unity is $e^0$, $e^{\frac{2}{3}i\pi}$ and $e^{-\frac{2}{3}i\pi}$.
But in WolframAlpha, when I was calculating $x$ from $x^3=e^t+5$ WolframAlpha said to multiply the third root of unity and multiplied $1$, $-(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$. I can tell that this is actually the cube root of 1 by cubing it. But how did this number pop out? I did some googling but got nothing.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. You say that you **do** understand where the number $e^{\frac{2}{3}i \pi}$ comes from, but not where $(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ comes from? These are the same number, merely in a different representation.

Comment: Do you agree that "Showing $e^{\frac{2}{3} i \pi} = (-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ and $e^{-\frac{2}{3} i \pi} = - (-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$" would be a more appropriate question title?

Answer (score 1):

We have $1 = e^0$, $e^{-\frac{2}{3} i \pi} = -(-1)^{1/3}$ and $e^{i \pi \frac{2}{3}} = (-1)^{2/3}$. This is the [polar form](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/polar-form-of-a-complex-number) of a complex number.

In this case, we can explicitly use Eulers formula
$$
e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x).
$$
Setting $x = \pi$ yields
$$
e^{i \pi} = \cos(\pi) + i \sin(\pi) = -1 + 0 = - 1.
$$
Therefore, for example
$$
(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}
= \left(e^{i \pi}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}
= e^{i \pi \frac{2}{3}}.
$$

---

*Note:* We also have $e^{-\frac{2}{3} i \pi} = -e^{\frac{1}{3} i \pi}$.
Can you show this with Eulers formula?